# Print text in second column of table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote this piece of code to retrieve text from a table from [this](http://racing4everyone.eu/formula-e-201516/) page. When I used it for the first column it works fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 #xbmc, xbmcgui, xbmcaddon

url = 'http://racing4everyone.eu/formula-e-201516/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')

for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].tbody.findAll('tr'):
    first_column = row.findAll('th')[0].text
    print first_column
```

However, when I try to extract the same data from the second column:

```
for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].tbody.findAll('tr'):
    second_column = row.findAll('th')[1].text
    print second_column
```

I get an error:

```
ePrix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addon.py", line 9, in <module>
    second_column = row.findAll('th')[1].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because all rows except the first one contain a single `th` element:

```
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<td>...</td>
...
<td>24 October 2015</td>
</tr>
```

You would need to find all the `td` or `th` elements from each row and get the first one:

```
for row in soup.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    print(row.find_all('td')[0].text)
```

`[1:]` here is to skip the first header row.

Prints:

```
Beijing ePrix
Putrajaya ePrix
Punta del Este ePrix
Buenos Aires ePrix
Mexico
Long Beach ePrix
Paris ePrix
Berlin ePrix
Moscow ePrix
London ePrix Race 1
London ePrix Race 2
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what if I want to get info from another column than the second? What do I have to do then?

Comment: @LucEvertzen sure, play around with the index: `print(row.find_all('td')[1].text)`, `print(row.find_all('td')[2].text)` etc.

Comment: I tried this, got an `list index out of range` error. EDIT: Figured it out, I'm currently trying to apply it on a different [table](http://racing4everyone.eu/f4ger/), which has a different structure. I'll get back at it.

Comment: @LucEvertzen yeah, that's because of the merged cells in the table. The last row does not have 3 tds - only 2. I think you may ask a separate follow-up question about how to handle it. Make sure you provide all the details. Thanks.